DBMS for multiple DB Enviroment Management
I have moved into a DBA role where I now manage multiple types of DBs. I used to manage only MS SQL and MySQL, but now I am managing MS SQL, Azure SQL, MySQL, MariaDB and PostgreSQL. I am currently using:

SSMS: MS SQL and Azure SQL
Workbench: MySQL and MariaDB
pgAdmin: PostgreSQL

Because of the number of DBs and clients I service, I would like to use only 2 DBMSs (SSMS for MS DBs and another for the other DBs). I just want some real-world experience with DBMS that will be able to manage MySQL, MariaDB and PostgresDBs.
I know Heidi is popular, but I don't like the interface. If it is my only real option, I will give it another shot.
I am willing to look at paid versions as well if it can assist in managing the 3 environments from the 1 DBMS.

I would like to use only 2 DBMSs (SSMS for MS DBs and another for the other DBs). Do not confuse - you tell not about 2 DBMSs but about 2 client programs which manages your DBMSs.

Take a look at Azure Data Studio
It supports all of these

Microsoft SQL Server
Azure SQL Database
PostgresSQL
MySQL

but not
MariaDB
not sure if this is on the roadmap

MariaDB reported as functional on Azure Data Studio issue tracker
